# Бинарный поиск в 10гб файле

Tags: php

Подскажите плз, нужно реализовать бинарный поиск ключа в файле 10гб. Читая по 4000 байт. Файл имеет вид 
ключ1\tзначение1\x0Aключ2\tзначение2\x0A...ключN\tзначениеN\x0A Где: \x0A - разделитель записей (код ASCII: 0Ah) \t - разделитель ключа и значения (табуляция, код ASCII: 09h) 
Символы разделителей гарантированно не могут встречаться в ключах или значениях. Записи упорядочены по ключу в лексикографическом порядке с учетом регистра. Все ключи гарантированно уникальные.

Костыльный код получился. Если читаем строку из середины и находим там нужный ключ, то все ок, а если нет, то при следующем проходе переменная $param[] не перезаписывается, а сохраняет все последующие строки. Что исправить?

```
$filename = "test.txt";

$file = @fopen($filename, "r");

$start = 0;
$end = filesize($filename);


while ($start < $end) {
    $middle = $start + floor(($end - $start) / 2);
    $lines = explode("\\x0A", file_get_contents($filename, FALSE, NULL, $middle, 4000));
   foreach ($lines as $line) {
            $params[] = explode("\\t", $line);
        }

    $result = array_filter($params, function($innerArray) {
        return ($innerArray[0] == 'ключ5025255'); //Поиск по первому значению
    });

    if ($result == true) {
        return print_r($result);
    } else {
        $strnatcmp = strnatcmp($params[2][0], 'ключ5025255');
    }

    if ($strnatcmp > 0) {
    $end = $middle - 1;
        } elseif ($strnatcmp < 0) {
    $start = $middle + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `$params = []` перед циклом по его заполнению сделайте и все.

Comment: `[$k, ] = explode("\t", $lines[1])` просто возьмите первый ключ и сравните. без плясок с массивами

Comment: зы: что за чудо-формат файлу вас что `\t` и `\n` вставлены "прописью" ?

Comment: Спасибо, поправил. 2ой пост не понял, только

Comment: вы получили свои `$lines`, после этого делаете цикл foreach и array_filter. все это можно заменить на строку из второго поста. Просто получите первый ключ из прочитанных в переменной `$k` и далее проверяйте его в `strnatcmp` своем

Comment: @teran, спасибо еще раз, все получилось, но обнаружил небольшую не точность в своем и вашем варианте. `$lines[1]` считывает позицию со 2ого элемента, потому что первый обрывается, соответственно, если мне нужно найти 'ключ1' он его не находит

Comment: не понял, в чем неточность. вы строку считали с произвольного места в файле. начало до первого `\n` будет мусором, его игнорируем, поэтому и берем `$lines[1]`. Вообще тут нужно компенсировать эти сдвиги, когда считаем новые `start/end` а то можно и вообще никогда не найти итогового значения, даже при его наличии. Либо получить значение не целиком.